# How to command automated tests to stay at one place of the monitor

Tags: python, macos, selenium, automated-tests

I'm running automated tests with Selenium and Python on Macbook and two monitors. The big issue with the tests is that the tests kept appearing wherever I was working. E.g. the test start on monitor A and I was googling or reporting bugs on monitor B. When the test teardown and setup again, but on monitor B.

It's very frustrating and restricting me from doing work when the tests are running. I am looking for solutions that can command the tests to stay in one place or on one monitor.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following to move the window to a set location:

```
driver.set_window_position(x,y)
```

x is the horizontal position in pixels and y is the vertical. So if you want the window on the top left side of your main screen you'd use something like

```
driver.set_window_position(0,0)
```

If you want it to appear on the screen to the left of your main screen x should be negative, e.g., assuming your screens are 1920 pixels wide:

```
driver.set_window_position(-1920,0)
```

You can also resize your windows if you like in a similar way:

```
driver.set_window_size(800,600)
```

Comment: It's not a perfect solution for me. I am on Macbook so it may have a 'Focus Follow Mouse Cursor' feature, http://osxdaily.com/2011/04/18/terminal-focus-follow-mouse-mac/ . I can get the tests onto another monitor. But when I am running 25 tests, they would load onto the monitor I was working on and move to another monitor one second later. 

From the link above, I tried to disable the 'Focus Follow Mouse Cursor' but nothing happened.

Answer (score 2):

Run the tests in a virtual machine. They will appear in the window you've logged into the VM with, which you can put anywhere you like or minimize/iconify and get on with your work.

(the actual solution I used at work was to hire a junior test engineer to run and expand our Selenium tests, but that doesn't always apply)