# Is there a way to make it so that the bot opens the tab on the right side of my screen instead of the left side?

Tags: python

I am using VScode to run a bot that I made that can open up a google chrome page. The problem is the position on the screen that the bot opens the tab on. Is there a way to make it so that the bot opens the tab on the right side of my screen instead of the left side?

```py
import time
import random
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

chromedriver = "/user/local/bin/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)

link = "https://docs/google/com/forms/d/e/1FAIpasdadTaerWE-ArYUfzNjfQosl_nlesd"
driver.get(link)

x_p = '//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]div/span/div/div[1]'
submit_xp = '//*[@id="mG61Hd"]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div/span/span'

while(count < 25):
  d = driver.find_element_by_xpath(x_p)
  d.click()
  time.sleep(0.5)
  submit = driver.find_element_by_xpath(submit_xp)
  submit.click()
  count = count + 1
  driver.get(link)
```

I tried looking on google, but since the question is really dumb and I don't really know how to rephrase it well, I would often find pages on a completely different subject.

Comment: Maybe you could show some code to let us know more detail

Comment: I edited the post so now it shows the code. Is there something in the code that is making the tab pop up at a certain point on the screen?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to command automated tests to stay at one place of the monitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44783953/how-to-command-automated-tests-to-stay-at-one-place-of-the-monitor)